# How do I compute the double integral of $xy(x^2+y^2)$ with $-3\le x^2-y^2\le3$ and $1\le xy\le 4$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do I compute the double integral of
$$f(x,y)=xy(x^2+y^2)$$ with
$$-3\le x^2-y^2\le3 \\[6pt] 
1\le xy\le 4$$

My approach is to find the points of intersection of the regions and use that to get limits of integration. Is there an easier method, or some kind of substitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Let

- $xy=u$
- $x^2-y^2=v$

and

$$du\,dv=\begin{vmatrix}y&x\\2x&-2y\end{vmatrix}dx\,dy=|-2(x^2+y^2)|dx\,dy=2(x^2+y^2)dx\,dy\\\implies dx\,dy=\frac2{x^2+y^2}du\,dv$$

Comment: damm. thanks man. I got it

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Well done. You are welcome! Bye

Comment: Why is the determinant involved in the solution of $dudv$?

Comment: @Cornman it is the Jacobian for the change of coordinates. In that case we see that the $x^2+y^2$ term cancels out.

Answer (score 1):

a different approach would be 
$$x=r \cos(\phi),\ \ y=r \sin(\phi)$$
and observing that
$$x^2-y^2=r^2 \cos(2\phi),\ \ 2xy=r^2 \sin(2\phi)$$

--- rk